# In The Matrix Resurrections, who created the modals?

Tags: the-matrix

Were the modals created by the analyst or were they part of Neo's game or both?

Answer (score 1):

Neo coded the modal using Matrix programming language. They weren't part of his game, but rather a side project that he'd been working on to try to understand why he feels so depressed and trapped.

We've seen other modals in the earlier films (such as the [Agent training program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgJ5ZEn67tk&t)) but none as detailed as the one that Neo coded, and none of them set inside the Matrix.

---

> **Smith:** *Is this old Matrix code?*
>
> **Neo:** *A little Modal experiment.*
>
> ...
>
> **Morpheus:** *An experiment? You put me in a tiny-ass Modal, left me to bang my head till I nearly lost my shit searching for you as an experiment.*
>
> ...
>
> **Neo:** *It wasn’t actually him. It was a program I coded for a Modal.*

Comment: This doesn't explain how Morpheus was in a REAL modal and needed to escape... Neo couldn't have created that, could he?

Comment: @MartySkip - It wasn't the real Morpheus. It was a program designed to mimic Morpheus. And yes, we're told that Neo coded it.

Comment: Are you saying that Neo coded an actual virtual reality that was capable of eliciting a Morpheus that would be able to take a red pill and become "real"? I don't see how that is possible. I understand a virtual reality game that Neo could make but wouldn't the Machines need to create an actual legit Modal designed to evolve real agents?

Comment: @MartySkip - That is precisely what happened. Neo coded a modal using Matrix language, then [populated it with a character based on Smith and Morpheus](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Morpheus_(program)). Eventually that character escaped into the world of the Matrix and then into reality (with help from the crew of the Mnemosyne).